# Can't get my IOS app to redirect to the paygates website

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using a paygate and the form submits and then redirects to the website. It works on all testing environments however as soon as I upload to the IOS app store, it does not redirect to the paygate's webpage.

The function to generate the hash works fine. However the form is not submitting/redirecting

```
<FORM action="https://pay.ozow.com" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" *ngFor="let item of data" class="iPay">
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                  <INPUT type="hidden" name="SiteCode" value="xxx"/>
                  <INPUT type="hidden" name="CountryCode" value="ZA"/>
                  <INPUT type="hidden" name="CurrencyCode" value="ZAR"/>
                  <INPUT type="hidden" name="Amount" value="{{totalPrice}}"/>
                  <INPUT type="hidden" name="TransactionReference" value="VAPP{{item.title}}"/>
                  <INPUT type="hidden" name="BankReference" value="VAPP{{customerData['first_name']}}"/>

                  <INPUT type="hidden" name="Customer" value="{{customerData['first_name']}}"/>

                  <INPUT type="hidden" name="CancelUrl" value="https://vapp.orz.co.za/cancel"/>
                  <INPUT type="hidden" name="SuccessUrl" value="https://vapp.orz.co.za/success"/>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                  <INPUT type="hidden" id="PvtKey" value="xxxxxxx"/>
                  <p><INPUT type="hidden" id="genHash" value="Generate Hash"/></p>
                  <p><INPUT type="hidden" name="HashCheck" value=""/></p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <button ion-button block box-shadow type="submit" class="btniPay" (tap)="doHash()">iPay</button>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </FORM>
```

I am not getting any error messages, the doHash() function works fine and it is generating the hash as expected.

Comment: Were you able to check the value of `doHash()` in prod? Also, is the form successfully being submitted?

Comment: yes so in prod the form successfully submits and redirects were you do the payment. also I have the console running for my app on xcode so when I press the pay button the values also displays correctly

Comment: Okay - so is the problem the callback from the payment gateway? What screen isn't it being redirected to? I thought it wasn't going to the payment page.

Comment: after submitting the form, it redirects you to the payment website url as shown above. However it is as if I can not be redirected out of the IOS app. as when I do that in ionic lab or anything like that. I see the connection happening to the webpage and then loading. But not when I am in the IOS app and I try the exact same

Comment: If you cannot redirect out I think your best bet might be an [In App Browser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/)

Comment: I will have a look into it, as I am not familiar with it. will it automatically redirect and still keep the values it needs to submit?